# binding model attribute in label - spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

It may be easy question, but i am new to it.

I am working in Spring MVC 3.0 , i have model object mapped with jsp form.

I want to pass model object back to controller once user submit form.

I have only labels in my JSP pages, and i have set something like this

```
<td>First name : </td> 
<td>
    <form:label path="RegisterInterest.firstName">${RegisterInterest.firstName}</form:label> 
</td>
```

Here `RegisterInterest` is my model object.

I want to resume value of `firstName` after user submits page.
Is it possible to set path in label and send value back to controller ?

I have one solution for it , by keeping model in session which is simplest solution for me but i don't want to use session in this case !
Also i can use hidden tags , but i have many fields in my JSP !

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ali I m just facing the same prob. Can u tel how did u solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a form is to enter something. That's why there are inputs in forms. If you want to keep some information hidden you can use .
But all informations which are kept outside input will not be taken account when you submit the form.

What is the idea behind your question?

Comment: actually i have jsp which has only labels and one check box (kind of confirmation page), and if any error occurs i want to display same model (page) with errors in it. previously we had kept model in session so it was not problem, but now we have removed sessionAttribute so somehow i need to resume model data.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example:

```
public class FormInput{
@NotNull(message="Name can't be null")
private name;
@NotNull(message("Age can't be null")
private age;
    etc etc
```

If you create a class similar to this one, that will hold all the data that comes out of your form, and pass that class in as a @ModelAttribute like this:

```
@ModelAttribute(FormInput);
model.addAttribute(FormInput);
return new ModelAndView(model, form.jsp);
```

As for your .jsp file have a look at this site to see how to use  and  in your spring .jsp 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/view.html

Don't forget to add
`<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>`
at the start of your .jsp

You can use `@Valid` when a POST is called to automatically validate all the fields and if you call `bindingResult.hasErrors()` it will print out the error message to the  field on your form without you having to code anything.

Make sure that the name you supply to your  tags matches the names you give your class fields.